# Apache running on Ubuntu stops working until I ping other machines on network from it

Tags: networking, ubuntu, apache-http-server

I set up apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty on an old laptop and it works fine as a webserver. 
However, I set up SSH and SFTP on it and moved it to another room so I could just FTP to it, and while it worked well at first, after a while it stopped serving out webpages - I got a time out error.

I tried pinging it and the resonse was 50% 'destination host unreachable' and 50% request time out. Tried to SFTP but connection times out.

So I went to the Ubuntu machine and pinged another laptop on the network from it, and this got it working as a webserver again. Does anyone have any idea why this might be? This always works. However the machine will become unreachable on the network within minutes of me doing this.

Ubuntu is set to not suspend no matter what and it won't lock.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some sort of sleep mode activated? I suppose you installed the desktop Ubuntu? Look at the energy settings! This machine should never go to sleep.

Comment: Yeah I installed the desktop version. I will look into the server version when I'm more comfortable with it. The power settings are set to never suspend, unless you mean some other settings? And it's set not to lock either.

Comment: Keep using the desktop version for local work. There's no reason to switch to the server version, unless you want to force yourself to become comfortable with commanline only. Did this work OK when you had the laptop in the same room? I don't think it's likely, but if moving the laptop to another room causes this problem, it might be related to the switch or router you're using. Maybe it's system overload?

Comment: When I had the laptop in the same room I was using it so it does seem like something is going to sleep, just not sure what? Unless like you say it's a router thing...

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/182400/how-to-prevent-suspension-when-a-program-is-currently-running

Comment: Still have this annoying issue... Any help? Anyone?